# count of duplicate items in an php Variable

Tags: php

HELOO ,

I have a PHP Variable like :

```
$var = 'Mark,John,Julian,Mark,Mark,Julian';
```

i want count every duplicate name and print them like :

```
John
Mark (3)
Julian (2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
$var = 'Mark,John,Julian,Mark,Mark,Julian';
$array = [];

foreach(explode(',', $var) as $name){
    if(isset($array[trim($name)]))
        $array[trim($name)]++;
    else
        $array[trim($name)] = 1;
}

foreach($array as $name => $count){
    echo $name . ($count > 1 ? ' (' . $count . ')' : '') . '<br />';
}

//prints: 
Mark (3)
John
Julian (2)
```

Comment: thanks brother , but i have error from your code `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line 3`

Comment: @omardealo That's probably because you don't have php 5.4 installed yet. To fix the error, just install php 5.4 or higher or just change `[]` to `array()`

Comment: yeah you are right i change it to `$array = array();` and working now so good , thanks agine brother

Answer (score 2):

the array_count_values() function could fit perfectly if you convert the string into an array.

```
$var = 'Mark,John,Julian,Mark,Mark,Julian';
$arr = explode(',', $var);
$count = array_count_values($arr);
```

Count array:

```
Array
(
    [Mark] => 3
    [John] => 1
    [Julian] => 2
)
```

Comment: thanks brother , i try your code and when i print array in a loop `foreach($arr as $name => $count){echo $name . '(' . $count . ') <br />';}` show me the result `0(Mark) 
1(John) 
2(Julian) 
3(Mark) 
4(Mark) 
5(Julian) `

Comment: @omardealo, you are using foreach on the `$arr` variable. but the `$count` array contains the result. change `$arr` to `$count` in your foreach.

Comment: yeah you are right , results now `Mark(3) 
John(1) 
Julian(2) ` but i already select the right answer , can you forgive me brother , thanks thanks thank alot